# Ubuntu Server installation stuck

Tags: system-installation, 15.10

Attempting to install Ubuntu Server 15.10 on my Lenovo X201 ThinkPad. I've gotten through the install process fine until while installing the system, it gets stuck at 76% on:

> Running live-installer-console-setup...

Comment: Can you add more details? What else was printed? Have you checked system logs in `/var/log/*`?

Comment: I donwloaded 14.04 iso and installed that. Worked fine.